# Import file size limit in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have changed all the php.ini parameters I know:
`upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`.

Why am I still seeing 2MB?

Im using Zend Server CE, on a Ubuntu VirtualBox over a Windows 7 host.

Comment: Impossible to answer. Changed where? "seeing" where? Are you sure you are modifying the php.ini in the path shown in `phpinfo()`? (That's the most common mistake)

Comment: I have changed the settings direct via ZendServer - and even via the linux shell (using sudo vi php.ini...) - when you create a database and then you want to import some data into it, the limit for the file size is displaying 2MB.

Comment: On Windows -> I was editing the php.ini file in the 32 bit version of PHP (program files x86/PHP) to no avail. When I edited the 64 bit (program files/PHP) it worked. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: After doing all changes mentioned in this thread, the max file size in phphmyadmin still reads 128M.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

You probably didn't restart your server ;)

Or you modified the wrong `php.ini`.

Or you actually managed to do both ^^

Comment: Hehe - I checked php.ini in use via and I restarted the server. I changed the settings via Zend Server - checked the phpinfo again, and the changes are there - but no effect on the phpMyAdmin form - when trying to import data/structure with a SQL file, I'm still limited by the 2MB.

Comment: Maybe something with my environment? But I wonder how many developers do the same - using a linux distribution on a virtual machine as a local web server, for development. I guess a lot out there...

Comment: i had the same problem, i use XAMPP under Windows, the php info displays upload_max_filesize=128M, but in phpMyAdmin still display 8,192KB , whats wrong ¬¬

Comment: I just updated both 'post-max-size' and 'upload_max_filesize' to 128MB and after restarting apache, phpmyadmin would accept a 128MB file. (Using wamp in win xp).

Comment: Some users also said that post_max_size and memory_limit need to be larger than upload_max_filesize.

Comment: "did you try turnin it off and back on again"- IT Crowd

Comment: This is not a answer. This should be written as a comment.

Comment: All above solutions did NOT work with me I using wamp I updated 'post-max-size' and 'upload_max_filesize'  but nothing change in PHPMyAdmin  after restarting the server I try to update PHP, MariaDB, and apache last to verion

Comment: For those using WAMP, see [gael's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55754044/4845615)

Answer (score 427):

Find the file called: `php.ini` on your server and follow below steps

With apache2 and php5 installed you need to make three changes in the php.ini file.  First open the file for editing, e.g.:

`sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

OR

`sudo gedit /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

Next, search for the `post_max_size` entry, and enter a larger number than the size of your database (15M in this case), for example:

```
post_max_size = 25M
```

Next edit the entry for `memory_limit` and give it a larger value than the one given to `post_max_size`.

Then ensure the value of `upload_max_filesize` is smaller than `post_max_size`.

The order from biggest to smallest should be:

```
    memory_limit
    post_max_size
    upload_max_filesize
```

After saving the file, restart apache (e.g. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`) and you are set.

Don't forget to `Restart Apache Services` for changes to be applied.

Comment: some time you need to change time out also

Comment: also add $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0; to config-inc.php

Comment: Note that the php.ini file listed in phpinfo ("Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php/7.0/cgi/php.ini") was not the one that had to be edited. Instead it was the one listed here! ("/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini").

Comment: I just want to add a sidenote, that when using Virtualmin, the `php.ini` that should be modified is not `/etc/php7.2/apache2/php.ini` but the one for the domain you want to edit, e.g. `/home/user/etc/php7.2/php.ini` or subdomain `/home/user/domains/sub.example.com/etc/php7.2/php.ini`

Comment: The "For further details" no longer works.  Goes to a "page not found" type of page with the error message showing in Greek.

Answer (score 121):

Just change your php.ini(xampp/php/php.ini) file, it worked for me!

```
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
```

And, don't forget to restart **Apache Module** from **XAMPP Control Panel**.

Comment: This seems to be an excerpt from [Bart C's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25096446).

Comment: I'm using these changes when I need to import huge file for various devices.

Answer (score 54):

Increase phpMyAdmin upload / import size

By default you get a 2mb limit of upload / import size in phpmyadmin. That makes it odd and highly impossible to import larger files. You can increase the allowed upload size of phpmyadmin by editing your server’s php.ini configuration file. Usually in servers like CentOs it is located at /etc/php.ini.

Step 1: Go to php.ini and find the following and change their values to something more higher than your database size. (In this example i have used 20mb).

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M

post_max_size = 20M
```

Step2 : Restart your apache service for this new change to take effect. Usually the command to restart apache would be

```
service httpd restart (CentOs) / service apache2 restart (ubuntu)
```

You can also restart directly from their path like

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart or /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

If you are in a shared hosting and do not have root access or access to your php.ini configuration file, then the other way is to create a .htaccess file in your application root and add the following line

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

If you were still not able to increase it, please send me an email for more detailed assistance.

Comment: Same problem, it was post_max_size wich was limiting my setup, thanks!

Comment: @Abu Fahim: Applying `.htaccess` changes, doesn't work on shared hosting. Any other options?

Answer (score 26):

For uploading large files through PHPMyAdmin, follow these steps:

Step 1: Open your php.ini file.

Step 2: Upgrading Memory Limit:

```
memory_limit = 750M
```

Step 3: Upgrading Maximum size to post:

`post_max_size = 750M`

Step 4: Upgrading Maximum file-size to upload:

`upload_max_filesize = 1000M`

Step 5: Upgrading Maximum Execution Time:

`max_execution_time = 5000`

Step 6: Upgrading Maximum Input Time:

`max_input_time = 3000`

Step 7: Restart your xampp control panel.

Answer (score 25):

With WAMP, on Windows10, open

```
c:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf
```

and change 128 by 256 at the end of these lines

```
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
```

Restart WAMP

Comment: Above is the perfect solution for Wamp

Comment: Thanks !!! I was getting crazy trying to find out why php.ini changes were not working ...

Comment: Man I searched for a long time looking for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Check your all 3:

- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit
- post_max_size

in the php.ini configuration file

*** for those, who are using wamp @windows, you can follow these steps: ***

Also it can be adapted to any phpmyadmin installation.

Find your config.inc.php file for PhpMyAdmin configuration (for wamp it's here: C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadminVERSION\config.inc.php

add this line at the end of the file BEFORE "?>":

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'C:\wamp\sql';
```

save

create folder at

```
C:\wamp\sql
```

copy your huge sql file there.

Restart server.

Go to your phpmyadmin import tab and you'll see a list of files uploaded to c:\wamp\sql folder.

Answer (score 20):

[image]

Open this file

edit these parameters:

- `memory_limit =128M`
- `post_max_size = 64M`
- `upload_max_filesize = 64M`

Comment: thanks for showing the config button, its been years since I looked there - makes it so easy

Answer (score 11):

This is how i did it:

1. Locate in the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

   ```
   post_max_size = 8M
   upload_max_filesize = 2M
   ```
2. Edit it as

   ```
   post_max_size = 48M
   upload_max_filesize = 42M
   ```

(Which is more then enough)

Restarted the apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 11):

**None of the current answers will work for WHM / cPanel servers.**

To increase the limit in WHM:

1. Navigate to Server Configuration > Tweak Settings
2. Choose the PHP tab
3. Update "cPanel PHP max POST size" & "cPanel PHP max upload size" (POST size should be bigger)

Answer (score 10):

Ubuntu 20.04, 20.10, 22.04, 22.10, and 23.04.

Well, with other distros as base Ubuntu as Xubuntu.

Edit : `sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`

Search and modify : `post_max_size = 120M` and `upload_max_filesize = 120M`

Replace 120 with the value you need, e.g. 22M, etc.

Important, you have to change to the version of PHP that you have by default at that moment.  Example with PHP 8.1: `sudo nano /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini`

To check what version of PHP you have, just run `php -v` in your terminal.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.
My Solution:
go to /etc/phpmyadmin and edit apache.conf
in the `<Directory>[...]</Directory>` section you can add

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

Solved the problem for me!

Comment: I had the same problem on Unbuntu 14.04. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have ubuntu 20.04 and my issue is solved by this one.Thanks bro

Answer (score 6):

I found the problem and am post hete if anyone followed some blog post out there to create the sort of enviromment I have (win 7 host with ubuntu and zend server ce on virtual box).

The thing is that MySQL is running on Lighttpd, not under Apache. So I had to change the php.ini file under that webserver as well which is in the path:

/usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/etc/php-fcgi.ini

In the end, you were right about the files, of course, but I was wrong on what file I had to change :)

Comment: uuh, that's nasty. Glad I have only Lighty installed and nothing more. That way I can't mix anything up ^^

Answer (score 6):

C:\xampp\php\php.ini in my case
or it could be C:\php\php.ini if the Apache / PHP / MySQL are stand alone

`upload_max_filesize = 2M` by default

so it can be changed as desired. And in my case 
`upload_max_filesize = 20M`

`post_max_size = 8M` by default 
it should be changed to `post_max_size = 20M` as well

memory_limit=128M is by default and it is not necessary to change to increase the max
2056kb or 2mb .sql file upload limit. But it only means that a script can consume up to 128 memory when you run apache and sql server , and if you change memory_limit=128M to higher and run any malfunctioned script then it may cause you trouble. So its up to you.

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem with changing the upload size on my phpmyadmin and OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks.
At first I didn't know where the php.ini is so used locate

```
locate php.ini
```

which came back with

```
/private/etc/php.ini.default
/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
```

I've tried editing /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini and then restart in the server put this didn't work.

I remembered that there is a better way to find out this file I'm looking for or and least where php is looking for php.ini.

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

came back saying that it expects /etc/php.ini but I didn't have one there. The below is from the phpinfo():

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
```

It turns out that the first result in the locate command above is what I'm looking for.

At least in OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks (OS X is something new to me) /etc is actually a link, etc -> private/etc, and by the looks of it PHP assumes default values unless php.ini is actually present.

I copied /private/etc/php.ini.default

```
cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini
```

Then checked the variables in the new /etc/php.ini as per Aditya Bhatt advice above and it worked.
In my case the values were:

```
memory_limit =128M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Obviously, the apache service has to be restarted to see the changes.

Answer (score 6):

```
 php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
    php_value post_max_size 100M
```

increse that size in php.ini then run command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service mysql restart
```

in xammp

```
restart all service
```

Comment: Be careful how you increase the size of upload in production as its a potential DoS security risk.

Comment: Yes, I know hackers may down your server through the Ip bouncing with a fake bunch of requests.

Answer (score 5):

How to import huge amount of Data in Xampp

It’s the best solution to open new, clean database, and import the file in phpMyAdmin. Choose file from local folder and leave all settings as is. That should be it.

But if your file exceeded file size of 2MB (that is default value in xampp installation) than you need to tweak some out. Basically we will just increase the maximum upload file size.

Open your xampp install folder and go to php folder. With some text editor file (notepad++) open the file called php.ini (by type windows describe it as configuration settings) and edit the line (cca. 770, or press ctrl+f  in notepad++ to find it):

`post_max_size = 2M`

instead 2M, put wanted maximum file size (16MB for example but not higher than 128M),

after that go to this line:
max_execution_time = 30
instead 30, increase execution time that’s in seconds (90 for example), also you need to change this line:

```
max_input_time = 60
```

instead 60, increase input time in seconds (120 for example)
and top of all you have to change this line:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

instead of 2M, increase to 16M for example.
Save the file, restart apache and mysql in xampp and try to upload again, if you follow correctly you should be able to import files through 16MB (example)

Answer (score 4):

You could just use MySQL administrator app or MySQL workbench.
Lightweight apps and you can export or import your entire server however the size.
Am late to the party here but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, My upload limit was 2 MB, I edited my php.ini, and I set it to 5 MB but still it was showing 2 MB even after restarting server. Than I compressed my .sql file to zip by keeping its name as xyz.sql.zip so it became 451 kb from 3.5 mb. Then I uploaded it again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 20.04:

Changing php.ini files and restarting apache was not enough, I had to also do this:

```
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that increasing the upload and post limit in php.ini did not affect the limit in phpmyadmin.  This is because my server has a separate setting for cpanel upload limit.  If you have access to WHM, you probably have this.

To adjust:

- login to your WHM panel: this is usually located at {your server ip}/whm and you will need your root login details here.  If you don't have those, request them from your host.
- once logged in, in the top left search bar, search for "tweak settings"
- On the tweak setting pages, search for "cPanel PHP max upload size"
- Adjust the number and save

No need to restart apache or anything, changes are instant.  This process increased the value of max upload file size in phpmyadmin.  You can check this by going to phpmyadmin and selecting your database, then clicking "import" at the top.  Beside the file selector you will see the upload limit.  My server default was 100.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I also had to add the line "FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824" (without the quotes) in /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf. It's documented here http://forum.ispsystem.com/en/showthread.php?p=6611 .  Since mod_fcgid 2.3.6, they changed the default for FcgidMaxRequestLen from 1GB to 128K (see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/mod_fcgid/trunk/CHANGES-FCGID )

Answer (score 3):

do the following things

- increase upload_max_file_size in php.ini
- gzip your sql file

and then import the file

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem where increasing max size in `php.ini` has no effect on wordpress and tried many solutions like -:

1. Increase max size via `functions.php`
2. Increase max size via `.htaccess` file.

The one that worked for me is adding max size in `.htaccess` file.
It wasn't working with neither with `php.ini` file nor with `functions.php` file.

I just did add this code in `.htaccess` file and its done

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

**NOTE**: I did add above code in `<IfModule>` tag.

If `php.ini` file is not doing anything in changing size then try other 2 files for it and one of them will surely work for you.

[READ THIS ARTICLE TO KNOW ABOUT ALL FILES IN WHICH YOU CAN INCREASE MAX SIZE](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 3):

I think if your php version is above `5.5`, let say it is `5.6`, then your `php.ini` file is in following folder

```
/etc/php/5.6/apache2
```

so you have to apply your changes like `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit` there.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

### Note: (added July 2020)

I'm surprised nobody else has mentioned this ... changing php.ini should probably be your last resort when increasing file upload sizes to something as big as 64MB.

It may not matter greatly on development machines, but editing php.ini to globally increase max upload size could be a really bad idea on a server where you have several websites operating. MySQL imports to PHPMyAdmin are often large, but you don't want every Tom, Dick and Mary uploading 64MB files to another site on your server because you need to do it every now and again for your MySQL database.

I'd suggest a better solution is therefore (assuming you are using the standard Apache PHP module) to edit the specific virtual host configuration for PHPMyAdmin.

On Ubuntu Linux, this is found in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
phpmyadmin.conf. On WAMP/Windows/Whatever you'll need to look at the setup for your Apache configuration, but it will probably be in conf-enabled, conf.d, sites-enabled, or something like that. These are actually often just symlinks to the actual file which is located somewhere like /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf (again using Ubuntu as the example here).

Your apache.conf file will include lines something like this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    # limit libapache2-mod-php to files and directories necessary by pma
    <IfModule mod_php7.c> 
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/:/usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/:/usr/share/php/Symfony/:/usr/share/php/Twig/:/usr/share/php/Twig-Extensions/:/usr/share/php/ReCaptcha/:/usr/share/php/Psr/Container/:/usr/share/php/Psr/Cache/:/usr/share/php/Psr/Log/:/usr/share/php/Psr/SimpleCache/
    </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Immediately after `<IfModule mod_php7.c>` add these lines:

```
    php_value post_max_size 64M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
```

Depending on your server config, you can probably achieve the same thing in an .htaccess file if you prefer. In which case you could just add the two lines by themselves (assuming you know for certain that PHP is enabled).

If you use fpm or fastcgi or something with or without Apache, the same more localized approach to controlling upload sizes can be achieved by using .user.ini files.

Comment: Good advice, but it did't work for me. Apache is using PHP 5.6 and the tag is <IfModule mod_php.c>

Comment: It actually worked changing the tag to IfModule mod_php5.c

Comment: Indeed, and on DigitalOcean hosting service, the phpmyadmin.conf file already exists.  adding the file limits works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I've tried all of the above and nothing worked for me: my phpmyadmin (on wamp) was still showing 128MiB (while I've needed to import DB which size was 212Mb)

so if U stucked as me you can import it with the help of commandline:

1. run `bash` (`cmd`, `powershell` or whatever terminal) from folder where your .sql file is located (or `cd` that path in terminal)
2. run `mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql` where
   `username` - is username for mysql server
   `database_name` - is name of db you want import to
   `file.sql` - is name of your sql file

for me just worked like a charm after 2hours of trying to manipulate this through php.ini and other configurational files

Comment: Thanks! I just had to first cd into `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.31\bin>` to run your given cmd. Then it successfully imported 650+ mb of DB in less than a minute!

Answer (score 2):

The first things to check (or ask your host provider to check) are the values of `max_execution_time`, `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` and `post_max_size` in the php.ini configuration file. All of these three settings limit the maximum size of data that can be submitted and handled by PHP.

Please note that `post_max_size` needs to be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Search for `php.ini` file

For xampp, you can get it @ `C:\xampp\php`

#### Find the following 3 properties and set there value according to your need

`memory_limit
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize`

#### Restart Apache!

Answer (score 2):

I am using Bitnami WAMP Stack 7.1.8-0 on my localhost. For me, the PHPMyAdmin maximum upload size limit was set to 80MiB as in the screenshot https://nimb.ws/fFxv7O. I managed to increase this size limit as explained below:

1. Go to the folder where you have installed the Bitname WAMP Stack, for me, it is "E:\Bitnami WAMP Stack”
2. Further inside, go to the path “apps\phpmyadmin\conf"
3. Open the file httpd-app.conf in your favorite text editor
4. Find the following two lines:

```sh
php_value upload_max_filesize 80M    
php_value post_max_size 80M
```

(The 80M value at the end of these lines may be different for you)

5. Go ahead and change these values at the end of these two lines (80M in this case) according to your needs.
6. Restart WAMP server.

Now go to PHPMyAdmin and see, your upload size limit should be updated to whatever you set it to. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

If everything doesn't work just check which php.ini you are editing.

I edited php.ini in this path --> /usr/local/php/php.ini

But it didn't work.

I am using Centos 7 and for that the php.ini file was in this path --> /etc/php.ini