# I can't import a .sql backup in PhpMyAdmin because the file is too big, what can I do?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-backup

I am trying to upload a database backup into my local MySql database using PhpMyAdmin

When I try to import my .sql backup file it go into error and it say to me that maybe the file is too big (31 mb)

Reading the documentation it seems to me that I can change some configuration file to change the size value but I can't find this configuration file and this value

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

The phpMyAdmin manual has [several alternative suggestions](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems).

These include:

- Using the [`$cfg['UploadDir']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir) feature to upload the file to the web server, which can help overcome upload or timeout limitations,
- Using a third-party utility especially designed for this purpose, such as [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php), or
- Using the MySQL command line interface, when shell access is available.

Answer (score 1):

You should import from command line, here you will not need to change configuration

Linux Shell

```
shell> mysqldump db_name < backup-file.sql
```

Windows CMD

```
mysql.exe -p -u[user] [database] < backup-file.sql
```

And for phpMyAdmin import file size [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958615/import-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin)