# impresspages database large at 3mb. ip_widget has many rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, impresspages

I am working with Xampp during development and regularly `export/download/import` the database via `phpMyAdmin`. Now it is 3Mb and too large to complete a simple import (2Mb max.). I note that the `ip_widget` table has over 11,000 rows and is occupying 2.6Mb of the database. Is there a way to make this database a size where it can be downloaded and imported via `phpMyAdmin`?

[image]

Comment: you can exclude table while exporting/importing but 3mb is not so large, so you can update your settings to be able import larger files, you can find an answer for that here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14612658

Comment: Thanks rtuszk. I will look into the article on changing default size for upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImpressPages saves all revisions of all pages to allow you to revert any page. To remove old information go to **Config**, add click **Advanced options** and select **Remove old page revisions** checkbox. Then visit **System** and click **Clear cache**.

Nevertheless, 2 Megabites is a very small amount of data. Change phpMyAdmin configuration (actually, PHP settings) to allow bigger upload size. When you reach hundreds of Megs, then you can think about optimization.

Comment: Hi Audrius, thanks for your response and support. I followed your instructions (also  changing 'Days to keep revisions' to 0) but this didn't change the size of the database, ip_widget is still the same size.Thanks for the information on changing upload size, I'll contact my host,

Comment: It takes time for cron to execute the cleaning. Anyways, I believe it cleans old data that is older than 30 days. Therefore, if you create a lot of content in very short period of time, you won't feel the difference.

Comment: Hi Audrius, thanks for follow up. The old versions are gone now.