# Trying to increase file upload limit for phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having an issue with `phpmyadmin` where the max file upload size stays constant at `128MiB`. I have read other issues extensively and have already run `phpinfo()` to make sure i'm loading the right file. The `ini` files it is loading are:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path = `C:\Windows`
Loaded Configuration File = `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini`

These files have been updated so that the following parameters are as follows:

- memory_limit = 1500M
- upload_max_filesize = 1028M
- post_max_size = 1028M
- max_execution_time = 500

Further more the phpinfo() function returns these values for both local and master values. Additonally, I am using wamp server and have not only restarted all the services as well as restarted my computer. Despite this the phpmyadmin file upload function stays at 128MiB.

The reason this is an issue is due to the fact the data I need to import is an extremely large .csv the current one is 350MB however I expect to have to import one that is at least 3GB. I'm completely at a loss as to how I should continue with this.

Comment: Might be a phpmyadmin limitation,try another client like http://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import file size limit in PHPMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958615/import-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Using phpmyadmin to import multi-gigabyte csv files will likely fail, and will definitely be hard to verify. Split up those huge files into 50MiB chunks or load them another way. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944872/import-big-csv-file-into-mysql

Comment: https://youtu.be/LKEZPVujTgI see here

Answer (score 0):

Find the `php.ini` file.

Find this and change it:

```
post_max_size = 128M
```

Change the values of theese like this

```
memory_limit = 2000M
post_max_size = 4000M
upload_max_filesize = 5000M
```

Restart apache, and you are good to go.

EDIT:

As you can see, `memory_limit` is lower than `post_max_size` that is lower than `upload_max_filesize`. You need to put values like these in order to workaround upload.

Comment: Values. As you can see, memory limit is lower than post_max_size that is lower than upload_max_filesize. You need to put values like these in order to workaround upload.

Comment: If you upload a file of size `5000M` will you get it in `$_FILES` and if you want to read this file can you with the above limits?

Comment: He needs to import file that is more than 3GB. So, draw conclusion from this.