# Import Big csv file into mySql

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import 300 mg csv file into mySql table. I am using this command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/csv/bigCSV.csv' IGNORE 
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

And it works great with small files (1 mg and so on), but when I try to load a big file like the one mentioned, MySql Workbench (which I use to execute my queries) runs the command, everything ok and green but 0 rows affected. No changes at all in the table.

I am 10000% sure that the table is ok because when I take a portion of that file, eg 1mg and load it into the same table it works fine.

Did anyone had this kind of problems?

Thank you.

Comment: Anything from the logs? Server or client? It is possible that you are running into a timeout problem, to be sure I would need to see the logs.

Comment: Try from the MySQL Command-Line.

Comment: I am using my own computer as a Server. It doesn look as a timeout because it states as finished. Here is the log: 15:44:29 LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/csv/bigSCV.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0 1.529 sec

Comment: @wchiquito - Did't tried that. Good idea, I'l give it a try now.

Comment: @Mihai, Yes, I just put that as a reference, my table is called test1 on my Server.

Comment: @wchiquito - from the MySql 5.6 command line client I got  ERROR 1046 <3D000>: No database selected. That`s strange.

Comment: When you enter the command line write `USE yourdbname;` since mysql doesn't know which db you want.

Comment: @Mihai , Thanks , I have learned that the hard way :). Not really familiar with command line tool. After changing the dataBase my querry works and it is identical as in MySql Workbench. " Querry OK, 0 rows affected <1.43 sec> Records: 0  Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 0

Comment: Are you sure the data is different since you use ignore?

Comment: Yes. I have tried even with an empty table to import the 300 mg file, again nothing changed. I have tried everything till now, not having a faintness idea what's wrong...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have "solved" it. Don`t know why and I feel stupid for not playing with the statement earlier but like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/csv/eventsbig.csv' IGNORE 
INTO TABLE std9
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Without the "IGNORE 1 LINES" at the end and it works with files of any size.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work well for more complex CSV data, where you have escaping complying with the CSV RFC.

Comment: thank you so much I just imported 9.000.000 entrys(4gb) in 2mins <3

Comment: @DouglasGaskell, what's the solution in that case?

Comment: @GitHunter0 Write your own parser (Not recommended), or use an existing one (easy, recommended), and then handle the insertions yourself? It's not as easy as this, and probably not as fast, but it'd probably take an afternoon to setup, and would probably run in reasonable time.

I did this with SQLite a while back, and was managing to handle ~100k records/s, which is ~6million/m, for >1billion records (~350GB). Though that took days to setup because I wanted it to be performant. Only worth it for repeated use, not one-and-done.

Or, there might be a utility that does this for you by now.

Answer (score 1):

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Learning\\App6_DBconnection\\CC.csv' 
INTO TABLE `test`.`ccd` 
CHARACTER SET armscii8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (`Cd_Type`, `Full_Name`, `Billing_Date`);
```

This will work even for large data sets of more than 1.5 million records.