# how to upload file more than 500mb at server using php

Tags: file-upload, upload, phpmyadmin

Please any one tell me how to upload file more than 500mb, because i am uploading file less than 500mb (like 470mb or 430mb). It's working fine but when upload 600mb 700mb file then  show error.

My `php.ini` settings are:

1. upload_max_filesize=2048M
2. post_max_size=2048M
3. max_execution_time=3000 (50 minutes)
4. memory_limit=1024M

File read is 100% but when goes to write then shows error.I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Out of disk space?

Comment: Wouldn't you mind to add server logs.

Comment: Uploading such large files is 1) Slow/unreliable 2) Unwieldy. It might make sense to use something like resumablejs, see https://github.com/23/resumable.js/blob/master/samples/Backend%20on%20PHP.md or google resumable and php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import file size limit in PHPMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958615/import-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Occur this error while uploading above 500MB file UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE (Failed to write file to disk.) when i use error handling using this parameter of file $_FILES['file_name']['error']. I match the error with php manual php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php