# Mysql is not starting in xampp :Unexpected Shutdown

Tags: mysql

Mysql is not starting in xampp.I am getting below errors . 
    I am getting 
1. Mysql shutdown unexpected 
2.This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3. improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

```
I tried changing the port . Its not working . 

**Here is my error log :** 

2019-11-27 10:14:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=17992
2019-11-27 10:14:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2019-11-27 10:14:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2019-11-27 10:14:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-27 10:14:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp1\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp1\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-27 10:14:10 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Increase the max_size limit in the ini config file from 12mb to the required amount

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import file size limit in PHPMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958615/import-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it will help you :

1.exit Xampp server

2.go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory

3.delete the ibdata1 file

4.restart xampp server

Answer (score 0):

Once check with these

1. copy From ...xampp/mysql/backup/... of all files and paste into .../xampp/mysql/data/

After copying restart XAMPP and check

2. If point 1 doesn't work, please uninstall and start from 0...