# 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes - importing a small file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The error message sounds obvious but I'm still having a problem.
Running Wampserver on Windows and importing a .sql dump file that does have some embedded pdf files in it BUT is still only about 6MB in size.

I keep increasing the limit in my.ini and I now have max_allowed_packet = 1000M - surely a GB is enough but I still get this error half way through the import.

Any ideas please...

Comment: Both client and server must set the `max_allowed_packet` option. The effective size limit is the lesser of the client and server configuration.

Comment: Assuming Wampserver is the server, what's the client - Presumably phpMyAdmin that I'm using to upload the file?? If so, I can't see anywhere to set such tings?

Comment: Read this answers on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958615/import-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin